# Comparisions using ternary operator vs if else vs switch case (Performance)

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I was searching for if-else vs ternary operator vs switch case but could not find any post with all the three comparisons. However, I came across some good posts and found that switch-case is faster than if-else. You may check the below one:

> [Why switch is faster than if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705955/why-switch-is-faster-than-if)

Then I came across some posts which said that there is no performance difference between if-else and the ternary operator. 
One of the most relevant posts is the following:

> [ternary operator vs. if statement: question of prettiness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192225/ternary-operator-vs-if-statement-question-of-prettiness)

However, I did not find any relevant posts for switch-case vs ternary operator.

So, I just want to know if I can conclude that switch case is faster than both ternary operator and if-else?

I know this is a silly question but I want to know the answer.

Comment: switch is not necessarily faster than if/else - it depends on several factors, including the type of the switch variable (int vs String etc.), whether the case values are contiguous or not and how many cases there are.

Comment: Just a remark: are you sure you want to be optimizing at this level? This should be a last line of resort - when you have optimized everything else...   Is your algorithm really at its best? Have you profiled your code to see if the bottlenecks are where you expect them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `switch` < `if-then-else` and `if-then-else` == `ternary`, then `switch` < `ternary`.

Comment: It seems so... :)
Thank you for answering one of my silly questions :)