# Multiple else if conditions, end with an other "else if" or "else" when logic dictates the last "else"-part dictates only one possibility?

Tags: java, if-statement

Sometimes you know because of the logic behind the conditions within your `if`, `else if` that your last condition check could be omitted and be written as an `else` instead. This way you do one less check, however it's less clear to read. What would be good coding? Would it even be more efficient because there is one less check or does the compiler optimize for these cases?

```
if(x<0){
  //statements
}else if(x==0){
  //statements
}else if(x>0){
  //statements
}
```

Or with else

```
if(x<0){
  //statements
}else if(x==0){
  //statements
}else{
  //statements
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `else if (x == 0)`.

Comment: `else {` clearly states that no case is left behind. I usually would comment `// x > 0` to indicate the intended value for x at this point, in case the other conditions were to change.

Comment: @rgettman Beginners error. Thank you.

Comment: In your particular example they are the exact same at the compiler still does 3 checks. The second example, from a visual standpoint, looks cleaner and complete. `else` tends to be used to prevent possible bugs or incomplete logic/output.

Comment: How is it possible that the compiler does 3 checks in the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, there is a potential problem if you include the condition on the last `else if`:

```
String whatIsX;
if (x < 0) {
   // statements
   whatIsX = "x is negative";
} else if (x == 0) {
   // statements
   whatIsX = "x is zero";
} else if (x > 0) {
   // statements 
   whatIsX = "x is positive";
}
System.out.println(whatIsX);
```

This will give you an error.  The reason is that the compiler thinks that it's possible `whatIsX` may not have been initialized, if none of the `if` conditions are true.  *We* know that's impossible, since one of the `if` conditions must be true (assuming `x` can't be changed by another thread at just the wrong time!).  But the language rules don't require the compiler to try to do the kind of analysis required to figure that out.

Because of this, it's best *not* to include the last condition.  Changing the last `else if (x > 0)` to simply `else` will make the program legal.

This is a feature of Java because of its "definite assignment" rules.  The code would work fine in most other languages.

Comment: So would you say that because of this definite assignment rule it's better to always do the last condition with an else statement despite the logic behind the options? I mean consistency in your code is important thus it would make sense to use `else` even if you don't assign values to a not already instantiated variable.

Comment: @Joop Consistency is important, yes.  Personally, my habit is to finish with an `else` without an `if` in such cases; the extra code looks redundant to me, and it could cost a few nanoseconds if your compiler doesn't optimize well.  :)  And that's how I do things in any language, even those that don't have definite assignment rules.  Judging from the other answers, this seems to be the usual practice.

Answer (score 2):

In you case you have defined it is ok to leave it out as there are only 3 possibilities.

That is

```
x==0 or x<0 or x>0
```

Considered a scenario with more possibilities it cry in for a bug when the last else is open ended cause if all the if's & else if's fail it will enter the last else as it has no bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It's even a bit worse than that. Some languages will not even allow an empty block. In Bash, in some cases, you can use a colon (':') for a null statement. In Python you can say 'pass'.

Let's not even consider, here, the question of mandatory bracketing for a 1-statement block.

I think clarity in code is **very** important, and compilers are pretty smart about optimizing conditionals.

If one could prove that an extra test is made that will always fail and it is in code that executes a billion times per second, well ... maybe then.

Otherwise, if one must leave out the else, one might put a comment to the effect that other 'elseifs' will likely be added.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, comparing the last if is not ideal as if the 1st 2 if statements are not true, then the third one has to be true. So keeping just else would be fine.

the ternary operator would be my personal choice though.

```
(x>0) ? //statements : (x==0) ? //statements : //statements
```

it basically reads

```
if( x>0) then statements 
else if(x==0) then statements 
else statements
```

more about ternary operator or if statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192225/ternary-operator-vs-if-statement-question-of-prettiness)

Comment: Ummm, ternary operators work with expressions, not statements.

Answer (score 1):

Last approach is correct since if it's not `= 0` and `< 0` then it must be `> 0` and no other possibilities left out.

On a side not, you can as well consider using a switch statement

```
    int x = 3;
    switch(x) {
       case 1:  x < 0;
               //something;
                 break;
        case 2:  x == 0;
                 //something;  
                 break;
        case 3:  x > 0;
                 //something;
                 break;
        default: break;
    }
```