# Defining const "variable" inside if block

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
Foo a;
if (some_fairly_long_condition) {
   a = complicated_expression_to_make_foo_1();
} else {
   a = complicated_expression_to_make_foo_2();
}
```

I have two issues with this:

1. `a` is a `const` and should be declared so
2. the "empty" constructor, `Foo()` is called for no reason (maybe this is optimised away?)

One way to fix it is by using the ternary operator:

```
const Foo a = some_fairly_long_condition?
      complicated_expression_to_make_foo_1():
      complicated_expression_to_make_foo_2();
```

Is this good practice? How do you go about it?

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, and in my opinion, yes, this is a good example of conditional operator usage.

Comment: Another option would be `const Foo a = compute_foo();` and put the complicated stuff in a separate function. Would make it reusable too.

Comment: Some discussion on this subject before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4192225/168175, from the other angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the **second part** of your question:
I usually put the initialization code into a lambda:

```
const Foo a = [&]()->Foo{
    if (some_fairly_long_condition) {
        return complicated_expression_to_make_foo_1();
    } else {
        return complicated_expression_to_make_foo_2();
    }
}();
```

In most cases you should even be able to omit the trailing return type, so you can write

```
const Foo a = [&](){ ...
```

As far as the **first part** is concerned:
 I'd say that greatly depends on how complex your initialization code is. If all three parts are really complicated expressions (and not just a function call each) then the solution with the ternary operator becomes an unreadable mess, while the  lambda method (or a separate named function for that matter) allows you to break up those parts into the respective sub expressions.

Comment: Sure, but part of the question is whether the conditional operator is a good way to go about this. And I think it is better than this lambda.

Comment: @juanchopanza: As far as I'm concerned, that depends on whether `complicated_expression..` and `some_fairly_long_condition` are just placeholders for function names or actually complicated and long expressions. Sure, you can achieve a lot by *"proper"* formatting, but that often doesn't hold when automatic formatting is at play and in addition, the lambda version allows you to break up those statements into simpler sub-parts.

Comment: Agreed. My assumption is that the complicated expressions would be put into functions if they are more than a few tokens long.

Comment: So, turns out my two expressions aren't the same type, so even the ternary operator doesn't end up working :/

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to avoid ternaty operator and your goal is to define the constant a, this code is an option:

```
Foo aux;
if (some_fairly_long_condition) {
   aux = complicated_expression_to_make_foo_1();
} else {
   aux = complicated_expression_to_make_foo_2();
}
const Foo a(aux);
```

It is a good solution, without any new feature ---as lambdas--- and including the code inline, as you want.