# c++ grammar, return value type according to this code.

Tags: c++

```
if(isRoot) isCutVertex[here] = (children>=2);
```

I would like to know whether return value is bool type(1 or 0) or int type(according to the value of children)

Comment: what is the type of `isCutVertex` as this is the most important part here?

Comment: vector<bool> is the type

Comment: What's stopping you from trying this?

Comment: so if children has a number more than 1 It returns 1, is that right?

Comment: Actually if `children` is 2 or more then it returns `true`.

Comment: @jay It returns `true` if the number of children is more than one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: assuming `children` is an integral type, which is why I was careful.

Comment: I am studying algorithm while reading a book, and It confused me so I asked a question. If it looked too easy for you I am very sorry, but I wouldn't like to procrastinate searching for the questions so I posted it as soon as possible.

Comment: thank you very much, I can again proceed with my study now.

Comment: You could improve the question by being more clear about the types of your variables. Also is `if(isRoot)` relevant?

Comment: so that's an ternary operator!

Comment: No, the only ternary operator in C++ is the *ternary conditional operator* `? :`.

Comment: nope, thank you sir! I will make it more precisely next time.

Comment: it operates like the ternary conditional operator, that's why I was saying that

Comment: so what you mean is technically it's different? (but works the same?)

Comment: Yes. The ternary conditional operator is *very* different from an `if` `else` block. Lots on this dotted around this site. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192225/ternary-operator-vs-if-statement-question-of-prettiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the *expression* `children >= 2` is `bool` in C++ (Cf. `int` in C).

The `bool` *might* be promoted depending on the type of `isCutVertex`. If `isCutVertex` is the `std::vector<bool>` specialisation, then no type conversion will occur (setting aside anything that might be done with `here`).

Answer (score 0):

the expression

```
 isCutVertex[here] = (children>=2);
```

infers that  this is valid

```
 isCutVertex[here] = x;
```

when x results to be either `true` or `false`

so you could have

```
bool isCutVertex[10];

isCutVertex[0] = true;
isCutVertex[1] = false;
```

or

```
std::vector<bool> isCutVertex2;
isCutVertex2[0] = true;
isCutVertex2[1] = false;
```