# Does ternary operator enhance speed of execution?

Tags: operators, ternary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speed difference between If-Else and Ternary operator in C…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754454/speed-difference-between-if-else-and-ternary-operator-in-c)

This is a very simple question, does the ternary operator increase the speed of execution in comparison to if else statement?

Comment: @FosterZ: If you don't have an answer to my question, don't make a comment here, keep your opinion to yourself, no one asked you for it.

Comment: i do have answers, but i wanted you to do a search first, don't just rush in here to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

No. Most languages parse it to a very similar syntax tree.  Any jit/optimizer is going to collapse it into 'basic blocks' of simple instructions without jumps; and from that point on it will optimize the same.

There could, of course, be some really bad systems out there for which this is not true; but gcc/msvc/c# will all deal with it equally well.

It's abundance can usually be associated with the fact that it is an expression instead of just a logic statement.  This makes it all to easy to do things like (note: really ugly example ahead):

`size_t n = strlen( pszVar == NULL ? "" : pszVar );`