# C++ Ternary Operator Calls Copy Constructor Instead of Move Constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I'm using VS Code to compile and debug with g++ in Linux.

Needed includes and usings:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Here is my class which is moveable:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const string& strA) : strA(strA) {}

    A(const A& a) : A(a.strA) {
    }

    A(A&& a) : A(a.strA) {
        a.strA = "";
    }

    string strA;
};
```

Example function that returns an instance of A:

```
A RetA() {
    A a("a");
    A b("bha");

    string ex;
    cin >> ex;
    a.strA += ex;

    return ex == "123" ? a : b;
}
```

And here is the simple main:

```
int main() {
    A a(RetA());

    return 0;
}
```

And returning value in the RetA function is **copied**, **not moved**. Why?

**On the other hand**, if we use "explicitly if" instead of ternary operator in the RetA function:

```
A RetA() {
    A a("a");
    A b("bha");

    string ex;
    cin >> ex;
    a.strA += ex;

    if (ex == "123")
        return a;

    return b;
}
```

Then it is **moved**, **not copied**. This is already expected behaviour. But it is strange that move operation doesn't work with ternary operator. Should it be like that or is it a bug or something for VS Code etc?

Comment: A possible duplicate of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914691/copy-elision-move-constructor-not-called-when-using-ternary-expression-in-retur).

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe the object is neither copied nor moved. Maybe return value optimization kicks in. It is mandatory, starting in C++17, even before that it was permitted.

Comment: Key line: *So copy elision is not allowed here, and there is nothing else that says that the lvalue expression can pretend to be an rvalue for overload resolution.* - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915906/14624729).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "automatic" move in `return` statement is limited:

From [Automatic move from local variables and parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters):

> If expression is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names a variable whose type is either
> [..]

It is not the case for `return ex == "123" ? a : b;`.

Then normal way is done, `ex == "123" ? a : b` return a l-value, so copy happens.

You might do

```
return std::move(ex == "123" ? a : b);
```

or

```
return ex == "123" ? std::move(a) : std::move(b);
```

to have manual `move`.

using `if` allows to follows the above rules with automatic move

```
if (ex == "123")
    return a;
else
    return b;
```

Comment: "return std::move(ex == "123" ? a : b);" works great. Thanks.