# conditional vs operator?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, if-statement, conditional-operator

In the GCC (version 4.8.2) manual, the following is stated:

> `-ftree-loop-if-convert-stores`:
>          Attempt to also if-convert conditional jumps containing memory
>          writes.  This transformation can be unsafe for multi-threaded
>          programs as it transforms conditional memory writes into
>          unconditional memory writes.  For example,
>
> ```
>    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
>       if (cond)
>         A[i] = expr;
> ```
>
> is transformed to
>
> ```
>    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
>        A[i] = cond ? expr : A[i];
> ```
>
> potentially producing data races.

I wonder, however, if there is a performance gain by using the `operator?` versus the `if` statement.

- In the first piece of code, `A[i]` is set to `expr` **only** if the condition is met. If it is not met, then the code inside the statement is skipped.
- In the second one, `A[i]` seems to be written regardless of the condition; the condition only affects the value it is set to.

By using `operator?`, we are also doing a check; however, we are adding some overhead in the case that the condition is not met. Have I missed something?

Comment: I presume the second form is faster as it avoids any chance of [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction) fails.  See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/311966) for details.

Comment: This is a bit of a grey area, since it mixes the vendor's model of multithreading, code generation, and C. You need to understand all three to make sense of this.

Comment: Just write code that is readable. Do not try to second guest the optimizer. That is a lot better than you or I at achieving that task

Comment: Quite worrying: **testing** the two constructions on the same input array, I get `1000000 loops: #1 = 4.428852 sec, #2 = 5.061400 sec`. (Without using the flag, of course.) This needs inspecting the generated assembler...

Comment: (On my test) Alas: the first gets converted to `testb $1, (%rdx); je LBB1_5; movb %dil, (%rsi)` and the second to the same code but with the additional write as well, with an extra jump in between. This tells nothing new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>What is says is that conditional jumps are converted to conditional move instructions</del>, the `cmove` family of instructions. They improve speed because they do not stall the processor pipeline like jumps do.

With a jump instructions, you don't know in advanced which instructions to load, so a prediction is used and a branch is loaded in the pipeline. If the prediction was correct, all is well, the next instructions are already executing on the pipeline. However, after the jump is evaluated, if the prediction was wrong, all the following instructions already in the pipeline are useless, so the pipeline must be freed, and the correct instructions are loaded. Modern processors contain 16-30 stages of pipe, and a branch mispredictions degrade performance severely. Conditional moves bypass this because they do not insert branches in the program flow.

> But does cmove always write?

From Intel x86 Instruction Set Reference:

> The CMOVcc instructions check the state of one or more of the status flags in the EFLAGS register [..] and perform a move operation if the flags are in a specified state (or condition). [..] If the condition is not satisfied, a move
>   is not performed and execution continues with the instruction following the CMOVcc instruction.

**Edit**

Upon further investigating gcc manual, I got confused, because as far as I know the compiler doesn't optimize transforming C code into another C code, but uses internal data structures like Control Flow Graphs so I really don't know what they mean with their example. I suppose they mean the C equivalent of the new flow generated. I am not sure anymore if this optimization is about generating `cmoves`.

**Edit 2**

Since `cmove` operates with registers and not memory, this

```
if (cond)
  A[i] = expr
```

cannot generate `cmove`.

However this

```
 A[i] = cond ? expr : A[i];
```

can.

Suppose we have in  `bx` the `expr` value.

```
load A[i] into ax
cmp // cond
cmove ax, bx
store ax into &A[i]
```

So in order to use `cmove` you have to read A[i] value and write it back if cond if false, which is not equivalent with the if statement, but with the ternary operator.

Comment: But does `cmove` always *write*? The caveat in this option seems to be that `A[i]` always gets written.

Comment: Bear in mind that unless `A[i]` is `volatile`, it's moot in the false case whether or not the move is performed. For non-volatile, the observable behavior in the absence of data races or other UB is the same either way. So when the code generator sees the transformed code with the `?`, it can decide whether or not to use a cmove instruction on that basis.

Comment: Relevant to the performance of cmove: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131096/why-is-a-conditional-move-not-vulnerable-for-branch-prediction-failure

Comment: What I don't understand, not being familiar with this optimization, is whether the code generator and/or vectorization pass can't just use a cmove anyway when they see `if (cond) A[i] = expr;`. This leads me to wonder whether this optimization flag really does have anything specifically to do with cmove as you say, or whether it's something else that helps "to remove control-flow from the innermost loops in order to improve the ability of the vectorization pass to handle these loops" (which is the stated intent of `-ftree-loop-if-convert`).

Comment: @SteveJessop I think you are right, this optimization doesn't seem to be related to `cmove`

Comment: A compiler might find it easier to efficiently encode the ternary operation into assembly. Gcc targets different cpus -- the entire `cmove` discussion is obsolete for ARM chips.

Comment: `cmovcc` can't write to memory anyway.

Comment: @harold Not directly, no, but a register can be set with the value from the memory, and a cmov can be used to set that register or not to another value, and then a that register is loaded into memory.

Comment: @bolov but then whatever `cmov` does is irrelevant. It may or may not always write to the register, it doesn't matter, you're unconditionally writing that register to memory with a plain old write.

Comment: @harold: bolov's latest edit shows it *does* matter. With the `if` construction, the memory may not be written, and using `cmov` it *always* needs to be.

Comment: @Jongware that's not due to the semantics of `cmov` itself, and you could do exactly the same thing with branches. I interpret his edit as showing precisely that it *doesn't* matter

Comment: @harold: but the *caveat* is that this flag will transform an optional write into an "always" write. That is entirely consistent with bolov's suggested assembler code.

Comment: @Jongware the flag matters, the semantics of `cmov` don't. My point is, the `cmov` is not the central matter here, it's about how the memory write is done.

Comment: Even without cmov, you could emulate it with addition and multiplication.  `a*c +b*!c` -- probably more cycles than cmov, but may be less than branch prediction fails.  cmov makes that optimization (unconditional write) faster by doing away with arbitrary addion and multiplication.