# My program works fine but my teacher wants it more efficient

Tags: c++

```
//#include conio.h   
//#include iomanip    
//#include iostream    
//#include string    

using namespace std;

const string Zo;
double Sp;
double Li;
double Ti;

void main()
{
    cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed);
    cout<<setprecision (2);
    cout<<setw(22)<<"Speeding Ticket"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please Enter Your Speed :";
    cin>>Sp;
    cout<<"Speed Limit:";
    cin>>Li;
    cout<<"IF School Zone Enter (Yes/No):";
    cin>>"Yes"||"No";

    if(Zo=="Yes")
        Ti=30+6*(Sp-Li);
    else  
        Ti=30+3*(Sp-Li);
    if (Sp>=Li+30)
        Ti=Ti+100;

    cout<<"Your Speeding Ticket Is:"<<"$"<<Ti<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

This wasn't my first trial on the first one it was `cin>>Zo` but the teacher said find a better way so if the user input is wrong it would know. I am a beginner so I did as simply as I could.

Comment: `void main` isn't legal C++. You also have no reason to make those global variables.

Comment: Your teacher is dreaming, in my opinion. This application is console-bound, not CPU-bound, so there are no significant efficiency gains to be made by recoding it. I probably wouldn't quite write it that way but I don't see anything 'inefficient' about it. But your teacher may have more experience than me, I only have 42 years. Ask him/her what he/she means.

Comment: that what the teacher wants us to use

Comment: try writing out your if else if logic on paper and see if you can use some algebra to simplify that

Comment: well, for one thing, `cin>>"Yes"||"No";` doesn't do what you want it to...

Comment: the first time i wrote the program it was, cin>>Zo;

Comment: Use int's instead of doubles.

Comment: `const string Zo;` is weird; it is a constant empty string.  Drop the `const`. Also make it local to `main()` like all the other variables; only use global variables when absolutely necessary.

Comment: If you want to get your own back, give all your variables meaningful names. If they try to give you a reason not to do that, get another teacher.

Comment: `const double fine = 30.0+(isSchoolZone ? 6 : 3)*(speed-limit)+(speed >= limit + 30 ? 100 : 0);`

Comment: There is no conceivable reason you should be trying to performance optimize code like this. It has substantial correctness issues that need to be addressed first. Are you sure your teacher didn't say 'more effective'?

Comment: So if the speeding ticket is negative does that mean the police patrol pays you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your teacher wants better math (which implies better logic our your app), one of possible variants is:

```
const double additionalTicket = (Sp >= Li+30) ? 100 : 0;
const double schoolZoneMultiplier = (Zo == "Yes") ? 6 : 3; // be sure that you understand when to use strcmp and when ==
Ti = 30 + schoolZoneMultiplier*(Sp-Li) + additionalTicket;
```

this variant do the same, but you see actual formula, so usually such code is better for understanding, also parts of this code can be executed in parallel by CPU

NOTE: you have problem with `cin>>"Yes"||"No";` - this just doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Using the ternary operator is not better math, just different syntax that can make the code look better (or worse if not used wisely).

This previous post shows that it indeed does not bring any performance improvement.

[Ternary operator ?: vs if...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else)

(Sorry can't put that as a comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

@vincentB (sorry I can`t comment directly on their post due to my rep)

The ternary operator can be more efficient than an if-else in terms of branchless code produced by the compiler

http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/04/10/cc-low-level-curriculum-part-7-more-conditionals/

Comment: Is this really true in Java?

Comment: I have no idea about Java and how byte code is generated and/or run in a virtual machine. Sorry.