# How do I turn a bool into an int?

Tags: go

I'm used to C/Java, where I could use ?: as in:

```
func g(arg bool) int {
  return mybool ? 3 : 45;
}
```

Since [Go does not have a ternary operator](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form), 
how do I do that in go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979178/what-is-idiomatic-gos-equivalent-of-cs-ternary-operator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
func g(mybool bool) int {
    if mybool {
        return 3
    } else {
        return 45
    }
}
```

And I generated a [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/QlGfrCptAM) for you to test.

As pointed to by Atomic_alarm and the [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form) "There is no ternary form in Go."

As a more general answer to your question of "how to turn a bool into a int" programmers would generally expect true to be 1 and false to be 0, but go doesn't have a direct conversion between bool and int such that `int(true)` or `int(false)` will work.

You can create the trivial function in this case as they did in [VP8](https://github.com/golang/image/blob/e162460cd6b5176292c0a160614547bab9a90788/vp8/reconstruct.go#L145):

```
func btou(b bool) uint8 {
        if b {
                return 1
        }
        return 0
}
```

Comment: I like your answer best, but while I was in the playground you linked to, I saw another referenced question and made this ugly one-liner:

return (map[bool]int{true: 3, false: 45})[mybool]

// See http://play.golang.org/p/7fDTkm_kKX