# Does golang have the equivalent of this Python short circuit idiom `z = x or y`

Tags: go

In Python `z = x or y` can be understood as assign `z` as [if x is falsey, then y, else x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), is there a similar idiom in golang?

Specifically the two variables on the right are strings, I'd like to assign the first if it's non-emtpy, otherwise the second.

Comment: Are you asking about a ternary operator? If so, see here for the idiomatic way to do conditionals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979178/what-is-idiomatic-gos-equivalent-of-cs-ternary-operator

Comment: Go is statically-typed. There isn't a concept of "falsey" in any type other than `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to use if/else:

```
s1, s2 := "", "hello"
var x string

if s1 == "" {
    x = s2
} else {
    x = s1
}
```