# bad character U+003D '=' in template

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm unable to conditionally modify a template's variable value in Go templates, due to the following error:

> `bad character U+003D '='`

Minimal reproducible example (derived from [the example in the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    type Inventory struct {
        Material string
        Count    uint
    }
    sweaters := Inventory{"wool", 17}
    templateString := `{{.Count}} items are made of {{.Material}}
    {{$a := 0}}
    {{if eq .Material "wool"}}
        {{$a=5}}
    {{end}}
    {{$a}}`
    
    tmpl, err := template.New("test").Parse(templateString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, sweaters)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

> Why am I confident this should work?

According to [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Variables), this should be possible.

And according to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725959), this should be possible.

---

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

### Environment

I tested this example in Golang Playground with version 1.21.4.

I'm running my original template, where I found this error, on go1.21.1.

Comment: `{{$a=5}}` -> `{{$a = 5}}`

Comment: ‍♂️ thank you! @tkausl

Comment: @tkausl if you post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.