# Is it possible to inline function, containing loop in Golang?

Tags: performance, go

For instance, I have the following test in golang:

```
// inline-tests.go
package inlinetests

func plus(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func plus_plus(a, b, c int) int {
    return plus(plus(a, b), plus(b, c))
}

func plus_iter(l ...int) (res int) {
    for _, v := range l {
        res += v
    }
    return
}
```

If I try to build it, I receive the following:

```
go build -gcflags=-m inline-tests.go
# command-line-arguments
./inline-tests.go:4: can inline plus
./inline-tests.go:8: can inline plus_plus
./inline-tests.go:9: inlining call to plus
./inline-tests.go:9: inlining call to plus
./inline-tests.go:9: inlining call to plus
./inline-tests.go:12: plus_iter l does not escape
```

Is there any way to let compiler inline `plus_iter`? If **yes**, is there any way to inline map iteration?

Comment: Rules for inlining can be found here: [Stimulate code-inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119734/stimulate-code-inlining/41119979#41119979).

Comment: There is no manual control over what gets inlined and what not, so: No.

Comment: @icza there is nothing about loops there isn't it?

Comment: I just did a quick test and replacing the for loop with the equivalent labels and goto statements allows inlining, which surprised me as I assumed there was some technical reason for loops couldn't be inlined.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> [Go Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki)
>
> [CompilerOptimizations](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations)
>
> Function Inlining
>
> Only short and simple functions are inlined. To be inlined a function
>   must contain less than ~40 expressions and does not contain complex
>   things like function calls, loops, labels, closures, panic's,
>   recover's, select's, switch'es, etc.

Currently, functions with loops are not inlined.

Answer (score 9):

As of go version 1.16:
https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#compiler

> The compiler can now inline functions with non-labeled for loops, method values, and type switches. The inliner can also detect more indirect calls where inlining is possible.