# How to assign the first non-empty/nil value?

Tags: go, null-coalescing

This can be done in python / javascript:

```
# Python:
a = ""
b = "test"
c = a or b # test

// javascript
a = "";
b = "test";
c = a || b; // test
```

Can the same be accomplished in go without doing some conditional block? The only way I'm able to do this so far is with conditional blocks...

```
a := ""
b := "test"
var c
if a {
    c = a
} else {
    c = b
}
```

I think this is answer is going to be "no, this cannot be done", but I figured I would ask just in case I'm wrong. The example here is simplified. The variables `a` and `b` could have been defined long ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [golang FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_formhttps://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form), `There is no ternary testing operation in Go. You may use the following to achieve the same result:`

```
if expr {
    n = trueVal
} else {
    n = falseVal
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979178/what-is-the-idiomatic-go-equivalent-of-cs-ternary-operator

Answer (score 2):

#### Go 1.22

If you want to assign the first non-zero value, starting with Go 1.22 you can use [`cmp.Or`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmp@master#Or). It's basically like a "coalesce" operator in Javascript `??` or `COALESCE()` function in some database engines.

```
package main

import (
    "cmp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a = ""
    var b = "test"

    c := cmp.Or(a, b)
    
    fmt.Println(c) // test
}
```

Obviously you can also assign to an existing variable; it comes in handy to simplify "if-nil-assign" idioms:

```
var a = ""
var b = "test"

a = cmp.Or(a, b)
// a is now "test"
```

The function is variadic, so it can take any number of arguments. The only catch is that it's also generic in `T comparable`, therefore **after instantiation the varargs must have the same type**. For more information about this detail, see [Difference between any/interface{} as constraint vs. type of argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628061/difference-between-any-interface-as-constraint-vs-type-of-argument/72284166#72284166)