# Difference between any/interface{} as constraint vs. type of argument?

Tags: go, generics, any

As generics have been released in Go 1.18 pretty recently, I've started learning them. I generally get the concept, because I have some Java experience from the past. But I don't get some implementation specifics.

For instance: when it's more suitable to use `any` instead of `interface{}`? Here's an example:

```golang
func printInterface(foo interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", foo)
}

func printAny[T any](foo T) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", foo)
}

func (suite *TestSuite) TestString() {
    printInterface("foo")
    printAny("foo")
}
```

Both implementations work. However, if I try to print `nil` with `any`-version, I'll get a compile-time error:

> cannot infer T.

https://go.dev/play/p/0gmU4rhhaOP

And I won't get this error if I try to print `nil` with `interface{}`-version.

So what's the use-case for `any`? When and which benefits does it bring, compared to simply using `interface{}`?

I'm asking to provide a *specific* example, where one implementation is objectively more suitable than another and/or where there is a *specific* benefit that can be evaluated.

Comment: This may help: https://go.dev/play/p/2abNLSPxw_v

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that not everything that can be implemented with generics should therefore be implemented with generics. Just because Go now has generics that does not mean that every function ought to be generic. Don't make the same mistake like so many Go novices that indiscriminately splatter channels and goroutines all over their code base even in places where it's not warranted. This applies to your contrived example where the only thing that both of your functions are doing is they pass the argument over to `fmt.Printf` which itself is not generic.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Beside `any` and `interface{}` being type aliases — hence, equivalent in usage —, there is a practical difference between *`any` as type parameter* and *`any` as regular function argument*, as in your example.

The difference is that in `printAny[T any](foo T)` the type of `foo` is not `any`/`interface{}`, but it's `T`. And `T` after instantiation is a concrete type, that may or may not be an interface itself. You can then only pass arguments to an instantiated `printAny` that can be assigned to that concrete type.

How this impacts your code is most evident with multiple arguments. If we change the function signatures a bit:

```
func printInterface(foo, bar any) {
    fmt.Println(foo, bar)
}

func printAny[T any](foo, bar T) {
    fmt.Println(foo, bar)
}
```

After instantiation:

- the function `printAny` accepts any two arguments **of the same type** — whichever is used to instantiate `T`
- `printInterface`, which is equivalent to `printInterface(foo, bar interface{})` can still accept two arguments of different types, since both would be *individually* assignable to `any`/`interface{}`.

```
printInterface(12.5, 0.1)    // ok
printInterface(12.5, "blah") // ok, int and string individually assignable to any

printAny(10, 20)             // ok, T inferred to int, 20 assignable to int
printAny(10, "k")            // compiler error, T inferred to int, "k" not assignable to int
printAny[any](10, "k")       // ok, T explicitly instantiated to any, int and string assignable to any

printAny(nil, nil)           // compiler error, no way to infer T
printAny[any](nil, nil)      // ok, T explicitly instantiated to any, nil assignable to any
```

A playground: https://go.dev/play/p/pDjP986cj96

Note: the generic version cannot be called with `nil` without explicit type arguments simply because `nil` alone doesn't carry type information, so the compiler can't infer `T`. However `nil` can be normally assigned to variables of interface type.

Answer (score 32):

`any` is an [alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations) for `interface{}`. [Spec: Interface types:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> For convenience, the predeclared type `any` is an alias for the empty interface.

Since it is an alias, it doesn't matter which one you use. They are one and the same. They are interchangeable. You can replace one with the other, the code will mean the same.

`any` is shorter and clearer, but only works from Go 1.18.

Since they are interchangeable, this also works:

```
func printInterface(foo any) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", foo)
}
```

The reason why `printAny()` doesn't work is due to it being a generic function with a type parameter. To use it, it must be [instantiated](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations) (its type parameter must be assigned with a known type). Trying to call it with `nil` carries no type information, so instantiation cannot happen, type inference won't work.

If you call it with a `nil` value that carries type info, it'll work, or if you specify the type param explicitly (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RiaiihSLEpr)):

```
printAny((*int)(nil))
printAny[*int](nil)
// Or
var r io.Reader
printAny(r)
```

And as said, `any` is interchangeable with `interface{}`, so you'll have the same code if you swap both occurrences (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/N6v901dFB2c)):

```
func printInterface(foo any) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", foo)
}

func printAny[T interface{}](foo T) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", foo)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite cover why this fails to compile: https://go.dev/play/p/0gmU4rhhaOP

Comment: But saying that they are interchangeable (in Go 1.18+) is not entirely correct, because the example in my question shows exactly the case where they are not interchangeable, i.e. `any` has a limitation compared to `interface{}`...

Comment: They are interchangeable. The error in question is not because the asker replaced `any` with `interface{}`. The asker tried to use a generic and a non-generic function. That's not the same. See edited question.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is not related to the usage of `any`/`interface{}` — whose difference is purely cosmetic — but it is type inference. As you can see from [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2abNLSPxw_v), if you instantiate your function with an explicit type, like `printAny[any](nil)` it will work.

If you have a function with generic type you need to specify the types. However the go compiler is very smart and can infer some types for you. But `nil` alone is impossible to infer.