# What is the "any" type in Go 1.18?

Tags: go, generics, any

In Visual Studio Code, the auto-complete tool (which I presume is `gopls`?) gives the following template:

```
m.Range(func(key, value any) bool {
    
})
```

where `m` is a `sync.Map`.  the type `any` is not recognized, but is put there.

What is `any`?  Can I put the type I want and hope Go 1.18 to do **implicit** type conversion for me? For example:

```
m.Range(func(k, v string) { ... })
```

which will give `k`, `v` as string inside the callback, without having to do type cast myself?

Comment: Related question (possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628061/difference-between-any-interface-as-constraint-vs-type-of-argument)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`any` is a new [predeclared identifier](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) and a type alias of `interface{}`.

It comes from [issue 49884](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49884), [CL 368254](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/368254) and [commit 2580d0e](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/2580d0e08d5e9f979b943758d3c49877fb2324cb).

The issue mentions about `interface{}`/`any`:

> It's not a special design, but a logical consequence of Go's type declaration syntax.
>
> You can use anonymous interfaces with more than zero methods:
>
> ```golang
> func f(a interface{Foo(); Bar()}) {
>    a.Foo()
>    a.Bar()
> }
> ```
>
> Analogous to how you can use anonymous structs anywhere a type is expected:
>
> ```golang
> func f(a struct{Foo int; Bar string}) {
>    fmt.Println(a.Foo)
>    fmt.Println(a.Bar)
> }
> ```
>
> An empty interface just happens to match all types because all types have at least zero methods.
> Removing `interface{}` would mean removing all interface functionality from the language if you want to stay consistent / don't want to introduce a special case.