# ParsePKCS8PrivateKey isn't parsing my PKCS8 encoded key

Tags: go, rsa, private-key, pkcs#8

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/pem"
    "encoding/base64"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    key := `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAqPfgaTEWEP3S9w0t
gsicURfo+nLW09/0KfOPinhYZ4ouzU+3xC4pSlEp8Ut9FgL0AgqNslNaK34Kq+NZ
jO9DAQIDAQABAkAgkuLEHLaqkWhLgNKagSajeobLS3rPT0Agm0f7k55FXVt743hw
Ngkp98bMNrzy9AQ1mJGbQZGrpr4c8ZAx3aRNAiEAoxK/MgGeeLui385KJ7ZOYktj
hLBNAB69fKwTZFsUNh0CIQEJQRpFCcydunv2bENcN/oBTRw39E8GNv2pIcNxZkcb
NQIgbYSzn3Py6AasNj6nEtCfB+i1p3F35TK/87DlPSrmAgkCIQDJLhFoj1gbwRbH
/bDRPrtlRUDDx44wHoEhSDRdy77eiQIgE6z/k6I+ChN1LLttwX0galITxmAYrOBh
BVl433tgTTQ=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`
    var ciphertext = "L812/9Y8TSpwErlLR6Bz4J3uR/T5YaqtTtB5jxtD1qazGPI5t15V9drWi58colGOZFeCnGKpCrtQWKk4HWRocQ==";

    keyBytes := []byte(key)
    decodedKey, _ := pem.Decode(keyBytes)
    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(decodedKey.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ciphertextBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    plaintextBytes, err := privateKey.Decrypt(nil, ciphertextBytes, &rsa.PKCS1v15DecryptOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    plaintext := string(plaintextBytes[:])

    fmt.Println(plaintext)
}
```

When I run it I get `privateKey.Decrypt undefined (type any has no field or method Decrypt)`.

Superficially it seems like this could be caused by an invalid PKCS8 key but I believe the key to be valid. Unfortunately, I am unaware of a way to test it's validity with [OpenSSL's pkcs8 tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkcs8.html). With [OpenSSL's rsa tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-rsa.html) and with [OpenSSL's x509 tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-x509.html) you can use the `-text` option but the pkcs8 tool has no such option. In lieu of that here's the output from asn1parse:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 340 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   20:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   22:d=1  hl=4 l= 318 prim:  OCTET STRING
```

Comment: You've just leaked your private key to the world. It is now worse than useless: it is a security breach. You must re-key immediately, and this time keep it private.

Comment: @user207421 - the private key is from https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa-keys . It's not "my" private key - the key was "leaked" _years_ ago. If it was "my" private key it'd be woefully insecure, anyway, as it is a 512-bit RSA key when best practices recommend 2048-bit RSA keys.

Comment: And voting to close the question because it can't be reproduced...  if I followed your suggestion then the problem really _wouldn't_ be reproduceable. Like if I hadn't posted the key the possibility that I passed a PKCS1 key to it instead of a PKCS8 key couldn't be eliminated.

Comment: Good to know it isn't a security breach. It would have been useful to have stated all that in the question. I don't know how you think you know who voted to close this question, or on what grounds. That also is a secret, and one which hasn't been leaked.

Comment: @user207421 - I apologize for the accusation! And this is a good reminder that next time I post a question with a private key that it wouldn't be bad to add a disclaimer of where the key is from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ParsePKCS8PrivateKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#ParsePKCS8PrivateKey) returns an `any` as key type, which is an alias of `interface{}`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71964388/9014097). The background is that PKCS#8 can contain different key types, e.g. RSA, EC key etc.
The concrete key type must therefore be determined via a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15), in the case of RSA, which applies here: `privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)`.

Possible fix:

```golang
plaintextBytes, err := privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey).Decrypt(nil, ciphertextBytes, &rsa.PKCS1v15DecryptOptions{})
```

or alternatively:

```golang
plaintextBytes, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(nil, privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey), ciphertextBytes)
```

Comment: [playground showing this working](https://go.dev/play/p/m8JgXWkW-WG)