# Generics mechanism for constraints referring to other type parameters

Tags: go, generics

Below is a generic `split` function that splits a slice into several equal sized (except maybe the last partition) slices based on input size:

```
func split[S ~[]T, T any](slc S, size int) []S {
    slices := make([]S, 0, len(slc)/size+1)
    for len(slc) > 0 {
        if size > len(slc) {
            size = len(slc)
        }
        slices = append(slices, slc[:size])
        slc = slc[size:]
    }
    return slices
}
```

The generic type parameter `S` has type `~[]T` where `T` is `any`. This works as expected.

The `~` is required to handle defined types, for example:

```
type X []string
```

Without the `~` in `S ~T[]`, `split` wouldn't work on an argument of type `X` (it would still work on a `[]string`).

Then there is this other `splitAny` function:

```
func splitAny[S ~[]any](slc S, size int) []S {
    slices := make([]S, 0, len(slc)/size+1)
    for len(slc) > 0 {
        if size > len(slc) {
            size = len(slc)
        }
        slices = append(slices, slc[:size])
        slc = slc[size:]
    }
    return slices
}
```

This function works on a `[]interface{}` or anything that is `type []interface{}`.

My question is, what exactly is the mechanism that the compiler is taking here to produce type safe code? Why are the two split function not equivalent. More generally, why can't `splitAny` work with, for example, a `[]string`?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr — the constraint `~[]T` refers to a type parameter, the constraint `~[]any` refers to **the static type** `any`.

---

The syntax `S ~[]T` is a shorthand notation for `S interface { ~[]T }`, where the constraint is an anonymous interface type. Either way, the `T` refers to the name of a type parameter which is:

- *constrained* by `any`
- in scope in that type parameter list

The key is that `any` is used as a constraint here, which is satisfied by all types. If you used a named constraint instead, that would be a parametrized interface as:

```
type Foo[T any] interface {
    ~[]T
}
```

and you would rewrite the function signature as:

```
func split[S Foo[T], T any](slc S, size int) []S {}
```

This perhaps makes it easier to see that the `T` in `~[]T` is itself a type parameter. Just like `T` can vary at each instantiation, so can `S`. When `T` is `string`, `~[]T` is `~[]string`

In the other case, the constraint `~[]any` doesn't refer to a type parameter. `any` is used a static type in the type literal `[]any`. If you used a named constraint instead it would be:

```
// no type parameter needed
type Bar interface {
    ~[]any
    // same as ~[]interface{}
}
```

And you would rewrite the function signature as:

```
func splitAny[S Bar](slc S, size int) []S {}
```

In this latter case, the constraint isn't parametrized and clearly can only be instantiated with types with underlying type `[]any` and nothing else.

You can instantiate it also with `[]interface{}` because [`any` is a type alias of `interface{}`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628061/difference-between-any-interface-as-constraint-vs-type-of-argument)

Answer (score 1):

In `split()` the type parameter `T` is the *element type* of the slice, so it accepts slices of varying element types, such as `[]string`, `[]int` etc.

In `splitAny()` the type parameter `S` is **not** the element type but the *slice type* itself! Which means the type of the slice passed can be `[]any` or a type that has this as its underlying type, but the element type must be `any` (which is an alias to `interface{}`), and it can't be anything else, it can't be `string` for example, so the slice type used for `S` can't be `[]string`.