# Is it possible to convert struct to ant.Any type?

Tags: go

```
type state struct{
    name string    
    zipcode string  
}
```

I want to convert this to any.Any type, plzz help!

Comment: I want to know that how struct to porto.Message

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to convert to the `any` [which is an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628061/difference-between-any-interface-as-constraint-vs-type-of-argument) to `interface{}`.

You can do

```golang
y := interface{}(x)

z := any(x)
```

But I'm curious why you need this, maybe you're having a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually I didn't read the documentation of types protobuf and asked here directly. My bad.
any, err := anypb.New(message). It does the job.