# Handling nil values in a map

Tags: go

I want to create a struct with the values in a map.

Here's a snippet:

```
        log := &Log{
            Facility:  parts["facility"].(int),
            Severity:  parts["severity"].(int),
            Timestamp: parts["timestamp"].(time.Time),
            Hostname:  parts["hostname"].(string),
            AppName:   parts["appName"].(string),
            Client:    parts["client"].(string),
            Priority:  parts["priority"].(int),
            Message:   parts["message"].(string),
        }
```

The problem is, if one of the values is nil, panic occurs. So I wanted to do something like this:

```
Facility:  parts["facility"] != nil ? parts["facility"].(int) : 0
```

But this is not a valid syntax.

Do I have to check every key separately to handle nil cases?

Comment: 1>if the data type is know in advance then you must use a struct or map of structs 2> data,ok:=parts["facility"]; if ok && data!=nil {value=data.(int)}

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form

Comment: See [What is the idiomatic Go equivalent of C's ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979178/what-is-the-idiomatic-go-equivalent-of-cs-ternary-operator/59375088#59375088)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 log := &Log{}
 log.Facility, _ = parts["facility"].(int)
 log.Severity, _ = parts["severity"].(int)
  ...
```

This will use the two-value form of type assertion, where the second value indicates if the type-assertion worked, and you then ignore that value, so the struct member is initialized with the zero-value if the map does not contain the key, or if the key is not of the required type.

Comment: Technically this is the 2-value form of the type assertion, not the map lookup. The nil interface value from the map is passed to the assertion which can then assert the interface to the desired zero value.

Comment: @JimB, you are correct I fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper for these types if you like:

```
func toInt(x interface{}) int {
    if i, ok := x.(int); ok {
        return i
    }
    return 0 // Or what you would like to have as a default.
}
```

which can be shortened if you want to use the default value for a type:

```
func toInt(x interface{}) int {
    i, _ := x.(int)
    return i
}
```

which will make it look like this:

```
    log := &Log{
        Facility:  toInt(parts["facility"]),
        Severity:  toInt(parts["severity"]),
        Timestamp: toTime(parts["timestamp"]),
        Hostname:  toString(parts["hostname"]),
        AppName:   toString(parts["appName"]),
        Client:    toString(parts["client"]),
        Priority:  toInt(parts["priority"]),
        Message:   toString(parts["message"]),
    }
```

You could go further and write your conversion functions locally:

```
var parts map[string]interface{}

// ...

i := func(name string) int {
    i, _ := parts[name].(int)
    return i
}

s := func(name string) string {
    s, _ := parts[name].(string)
    return s
}

t := func(name string) time.Time {
    t, _ := parts[name].(time.Time)
    return t
}

log := &Log{
    Facility:  i("facility"),
    Severity:  i("severity"),
    Timestamp: t("timestamp"),
    Hostname:  s("hostname"),
    AppName:   s("appName"),
    Client:    s("client"),
    Priority:  i("priority"),
    Message:   s("message"),
}
```