# shorthand c++ if else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I'm just curious if there is a short hand statement to this:

```
if(number < 0 )
  bigInt.sign = 0;
else
  bigInt.sign = 1;
```

I see all these short hand statements for if a < b and such.

I'm not sure on how to do it properly and would like some input on this.

Thanks!

I actually just figured it out right before you guys had answered.

The shortest solution is `bigInt.sign = (number < 0) ? 0 : 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ternary operator ?: vs if...else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else)

Comment: Thanks to all who answered this. I appreciate it, this is really the first time that I have used the shorthand if-else statement, so I am just trying to get used to it

Comment: @kevorski `bigInt.sign = (number < 0) ? 1 : 0` - this is the opposite of your original `if`/`else` code, but otherwise good.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not quite, that's more performance related. Although I'm sure there's a duplicate for this somewhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes:

```
bigInt.sign = !(number < 0);
```

The `!` operator always evaluates to `true` or `false`.  When converted to `int`, these become `1` and `0` respectively.

Of course this is equivalent to:

```
bigInt.sign = (number >= 0);
```

Here the parentheses are redundant but I add them for clarity. All of the comparison and relational operator evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Tbh, I'd just do `number >= 0`, but I'd put in a `static_cast<decltype(bigInt)>` to make it clear a 0 or 1 is desired.

Comment: @chris this is very basic c++ program that i'm making for school. just learning c++ right now.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, It's redundant, but the cast makes it clear that you didn't accidentally expect it to be stored in a `bool` or anything silly like that. I'd hazard putting in the literal type of `bigInt` for clarity on that. Implicit `bool` to `int` conversions kind of suck in general imo.

Comment: +1, but one minor nitpick: I'd use `bigInt.sign = (0 <= number);` so that the ordering reads left-to-right. This becomes more attractive if you have multiple comparisons such `0 <= number && number < SomeUpperBound`

Answer (score 63):

The basic syntax for using ternary operator is like this:

```
(condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)
```

For you case it is like this:

```
number < 0 ? bigInt.sign = 0 : bigInt.sign = 1;
```

Answer (score 25):

try this:

```
bigInt.sign = number < 0 ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: What, omitting whitespace makes it "shorthand?"

Comment: Just a stylistic choice so no downvote from me, but IMHO this is not the cleanest way to use the conditional operator here... `bigInt.sign = number < 0 ? 0 : 1` is better factored, and emphasises `?`'s use to select between values rather than using it for flow control.

Comment: You can also replace `?` and `:` with `&&` and `||` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you use this in your code you could consider the following:

**macro**

```
#define SIGN(x) ( (x) >= 0 )
```

**Inline function**

```
inline int sign(int x)
{
    return x >= 0;
}
```

Then you would just go:

```
bigInt.sign = sign(number);
```

Comment: The macro should be `#define SIGN(x) ( (x) >= 0 )`

Comment: i suggest revising the macro to `#define SIGN(x) ((x) >= 0)`

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind for the next time. I think that I will only be using it when I create the two BigInts so wouldn't do much for me at this point

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this :

```
bigInt.sign = (number<0)*0 + (number>=0)*1;
```

If we need to assign another value other than `0` and `1` then this code can  be used like :

```
 bigInt.sign = (number<0)*(replacement_of_0) + (number>=0)*(replacement_of_1);
```

Comment: performance based `if-else ` code is better than other methods I think.