# Identifying C++ code problems

Tags: c++

What does this mean?

I have problem understanding this because I'm not using this kind of format.

Can anyone translate this condition?

```
(D == 4 ? (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14) : 10);
```

Comment: Duplicate? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793916/shorthand-c-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 2):

This is two ternary operators. The ternary operator compresses an if-else statement into one line. `(expression ? fireOnTrue() : fireOnFalse())` For example

```
if(D == 4) {
    explode();
} else {
    explodeTwice();
}
```

could be written as:

```
D == 4 ? explode() : explodeTwice()
```

Therefore, if we take `(D == 4 ? (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14) : 10);` and break it down we get:

```
if(D == 4) {
    (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14);
} else
    10;
}
```

breaking that down one more step gives us:

```
if(D == 4) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        10;
    } else {
        14;
    }
} else
    10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through that monster piece by piece.

`(D == 4 ? (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14) : 10)`

This line uses the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) `x ? y : z`, which returns

- `y` if `x == true`
- `z` if `x == false`

---

`(D == 4 ? (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14) : 10)` first checks whether `D` is equal to `4`:

- if `D` is equal to `4` it returns `(i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14)`
- if `D` is not equal to `4` it returns `10`.

---

If `D` happens to be equal to `4` then expression `(i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14)` will be parsed:

`(i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14)` first checks whether `i % 2 == 0` is true or false. `%` is the remainder aka modulo operator which returns the remainder of the division a/b for `a % b`.

Comparing that result to `0` is the same as saying "divides evenly", i.e. no remainder.

The remainder for dividing by `2` can be either `0` or `1`, thus:

- `0` if `i` is an even number
- `1` if `i` is an odd number

In other words, `(i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14)` will return `10` if `i` is even, or `14` if `i` is odd.

---

In conclusion, `(D == 4 ? (i % 2 == 0 ? 10 : 14) : 10)` has can evaluate to either `10` or `14` depending on `D` and `i`, like this:

- if `D == 4` and `i` is even, it evaluates to `10`
- if `D == 4` and `i` is odd, it evaluates to `14`
- if `D != 4`, it evaluates to `10`

---

Thus, the expression could be simplified as a method to this:

```
int return10or14(int D, int i) {
    if (D != 4 || i % 2 == 0)
        return 10;
    else
        return 14;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression a ? b:c simply means if(a) then b , else c.
Thus assuming your expression evaluates to retval, it can be written as:

```
if(D == 4)
{
    if(i%2 == 0) 
      retval = 10;
    else 
      retval = 14;
}
else  retval = 10;
```