# Seek explnation of the Qt codes

Tags: c++, qt

I am a newbie to Qt and also have limited knowledge of C++. I am learning Qt using `C++ GUI Programming with Qt4` and have some doubt on the Qt codes in creating a dialog. Here as follows is a function of `flicked()`:

```
void FindDialog::findClicked()
{
    QString text = lineEdit->text();
    Qt::CaseSensitivity cs =
            caseCheckBox->isChecked() ? Qt::CaseSensitive
                                      : Qt::CaseInsensitive;
    if (backwardCheckBox->isChecked()) {
        emit findPrevious(text, cs);
    } else {
        emit findNext(text, cs);
    }
}
```

The source of the code is at [finddialog.cpp](https://github.com/mutse/qt5-book-code/blob/master/chap02/find/finddialog.cpp) 
I don't understand the meaning of the two operators `?` and `:` above. Anyone can explain to me what are they used for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shorthand c++ if else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793916/shorthand-c-if-else-statement)

Comment: `if (a == true) b(); else c();` can be written like `a == true ? b() : c();`

Comment: OT: Why would you learn Qt4 in 2018? The last version of Qt4 is 7 years old.

Comment: @ I have textbook Qt4 in hand. Do you have any good suggestion to learning Qt5.

Comment: http://wiki.qt.io/Books

Comment: @eyllanesc: thanks! I have also found a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c

Comment: @jingweimo: They have a [very good tutorials](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html) on their wesite and also many [basic examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html).

Comment: I recommend you take some time and do a search in SO since these types of questions have been answered multiple times, or learn C ++ first, that has nothing to do with Qt, but it is basic C ++.

Comment: https://qmlbook.github.io/

Comment: Qt4 is so close to Qt5, that learning it will not be counterproductive, if you have the book. Qt5 and modern C++ add very nice things, and better ways to do a lot of stuff, so once you move on to them, keep an open mind and actively seek out the improvements and changes and learn them. But Qt4 is perhaps simpler, so might be easier to get started with (and is not wasted effort).

Answer (score 1):

```
foo ? bar : baz; //With foo evaluating to true or false
```

is no Qt specific feature. It is a standard C++ feature: the [Ternary or Conditional Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_conditional_operator.htm).