# Where in C++ is Required to Use Conditional Expression (?:)

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I have a book that teaches C++ programming. In the book, it says "Conditional expressions can appear in some program locations where if…else statements cannot" The book doesn't specify where. 
I was curious if someone can show me an example where you explicitly MUST use conditional statement and not if...else statement.

Thanks,

Comment: Inside other expressions, for example, there cannot be an if statement (since you can't nest a statement inside an expression). Using it is never a "must", though -- every form that can be realized with the conditional expresson can be re-written with equivalently behaving code using `if` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, where language expects an expression. There are several cases where `?:` operator cannot be easily replaced with `if` statement. It rarely occurs in practice, but it is possible. For example:

```
const int x = (a > 0) ? a : 0; // (global) const/constexpr initialization

struct D: public B {
     D(int a)
         : B(a > 0 ? a : 0) // member initializer list
     { }
};

template<int x> struct A {
};
A<(a>0) ? a : 0> var; // template argument
```

Comment: Don't forget the creation of a reference, which is similar to initialization of a const.

Answer (score 1):

A conditional expression is an expression, whereas an if-else is a statement. That means you can embed conditional expressions in other expressions, but you can't do that with if-else:

```
// works
x = flag ? 5 : 6;

// meaningless nonsense
x = if (flag) 5 else 6;
```

You can always rewrite the code to use if-else, but it requires restructuring the logic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator in an expression, not just on statements. For example,

```
bool foo;
if (bar)
    foo = false;
else
    foo = true;
```

can be shortened to

```
bool foo = (bar)?false:true;
```

It's never necessary to perform an action, and just exists for convenience.

Comment: (and a side note: the above example can and probably should be written as `foo = !bar;`)

Comment: that's not a "command", that's a **statement** then. In C, there's no such thing as "a command".

Comment: What are `FALSE` and `TRUE`? (`false` and `true` are keywords.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry, I'm in WinAPI mode.

Answer (score 0):

'to initialize a constant variable depending on some expression' - says https://stackoverflow.com/a/3565387/3969164