# Does ternary operator gets expanded into if-else block during compilation?

Tags: c, assembly, ternary-operator

During compilation, when c code is converted into assembly language, does ternary operator converted into if-else block ?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else

Comment: There are no "if-else" blocks in machine code, only conditional jumps.  Ternary may compile into conditional jumps or conditional moves.  `if` and `else` also may compile into conditional jumps or conditional moves.

Comment: No. Assembly doesn't have an if..else.

Comment: Note that the ARM Thumb-2 instruction set has a construct that could be called an "if-then-else": https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/condition-codes-3-conditional-execution-in-thumb-2

Comment: Did you try it with your hardware?

Comment: In some cases, a compiler may produce clever code that eliminates any conditional branches, if the ternary expression can be converted into a sequence of math and/or bit oriented type instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Machine instructions (or assembly which, roughly speaking, is a higher level representation of machine instructions that a human can understand more easily) does not have an `if`/`else` construct.    At most, there will be some form of conditional jump.

Practically, `if`/`else` constructs might initially be mapped to code which uses conditional jumps.   And the working of the ternary `?:` might, initially at least, be mapped the same way.

However, compilers do some fairly advanced optimisation of code.   Depending on needs of the CPU, the optimiser might completely reorder or remove some blocks of code that have conditional jumps, and replace it with other code that produces the same results, using some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no if else block will be created in compiled c