# C++ ternary operators, Any difference?

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-operator

I was reading about the difference of the following:

1)

```
std::string test = level > 10 ? "Master" : "Beginner";
```

2)

```
std::string test;
if (level > 10)
    test = "Master";
else
    test = "Beginner";
```

And in the second case I was told that in the second option a temporary value is being create which I don't understand.

I learnt that when we declare a variable without initialisation it takes garbage, so the compiler just holds a memory location and doesn't "work" to change its value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary operator ?: vs if...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else)

Comment: there is no "garbage" in your example, `std::string` has a constructor that gets called. Strictly speaking also in general the value of something unitialized is not "garbage", you are just not allowed to use it and if you do you get something that can look like garbage

Answer (score 6):

Syntactically, the first case is somewhat equivalent to this:

```
constexpr const char* f(int level) {
    if (level > 10)
        return "Master";
    else
        return "Beginner";
}

std::string test = f(level);
```

Here, `test` is immediately initialized with either `"Master"` or `"Beginner"`. In the second case, `test` is first default-initialized, then either value is assigned to it.

However, this is not necessarily true after optimizations: the compiler can very well generate the exact same code in both cases.

> when we declare a variable without initialisation it takes garbage

That is only true for fundamental and POD types, not classes like `std::string` which have a default-constructor. Look up [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) for details.

Comment: *"However, this is not necessarily true after optimizations: the compiler can very well generate the exact same code in both cases"* - In the general case of a user defined copy c'tor and assignment operator, a compiler cannot prove the two invocations mean exactly the same thing, and so likely won't generate the same code.

Answer (score 5):

There're no temporary objects constructed in both cases.

In the 1st case, `test` is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the `const char*` returned by the ternary operator directly, via the constructor of `std::string` taking `const char*`.

In the 2nd case, `test` is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) firstly, then assgined from the `const char*` in the `if` or `else` branch via the assignment operator of `std::string`. (BTW: After default-initialization `test` won't *take garbage*, it'll be initialized by the default constructor of `std::string` as empty string.)

Comment: But when I access it I get strange values

Comment: @smith_brown I tried it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6pu9AsqhoSiBY0fe) and seems working fine. What do you mean *getting strange values*? Could you make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to use the first form, but the compiler would have grievous performance issues if it didn't produce the same code for either. Having said that, the first form is clear and easy to understand, and might give the optimizer less work to do, so you might as well use it. It clearly states the intent to *initialize* the variable to one of two given values, and the code that expresses intent most clearly often produces the best generated code (as well as being easiest to understand.)