# Ternary operator slower than if else when returning bool literals?

Tags: c++, clion

I know there is a very similar question already:
[Ternary operator ?: vs if...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565368/ternary-operator-vs-if-else)

This is more regarding returning bool literals from a function.

Given the following function:

```cpp
bool inRange(size_t value, size_t upperBound) const
{
   return (value >= 0 && value < upperBound) ? true : false;
}
```

CLion advices me this can be **simplified** using an "if else" statement instead.
Would this be actually faster because of return value optimization and/or likelihood of certain if branches? (or some other reason).

Or is it maybe a style guide given by CLion?

Comment: it's helpful if you post full message.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to measure both versions, but I suspect the assembly will be similar if not identical.

Comment: Simplifying code is subjective.   It is usually concerned with make the code easier to read for mere mortals.   Most modern compilers (if optimisation is enabled) will produce the same object code if you had written `if (value >= 0 && value < upperBound) return true; else return false;` - and a fair few people (and some formal style guides) deem that more readable.    Personally, I would just do `return (value >= 0 && value < upperBound)` or (since `value` is unsigned) `return value < upperBound` - but that's ALSO a subjective judgement.

Answer (score 5):

The recommendation it is suggesting is to change

```
bool inRange(size_t value, size_t upperBound) const
{
   return (value >= 0 && value < upperBound) ? true : false;
}
```

to

```
bool inRange(size_t value, size_t upperBound) const
{
   return value >= 0 && value < upperBound;
}
```

this has nothing to do with performance, the ternary is simply redundant. I am quite positive it would compile to the same assembly ([proof](https://godbolt.org/z/o4xs8ej5P)), the IDE is just suggesting you simplify your redundant logic.

Comment: In addition, the `value >= 0` is also redundant for unsigned values. The compiler indeed did not generate code to check that.