# What does this do?

Tags: c, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The ternary (conditional) operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c)

This is a code example from my teacher assistance. I don't have a clue what `total = total*2+ (n=='1'? 1:0);` does. I think it multiply the total with by 2, but what is with the question mark and the `1:0` ratio ?

```
int bcvt(FILE *infile){
  char n;
  int i, total=0;
  for(i=0; i<32; i++){    
    fscanf(infile, "%c", &n);
    total = total*2+ (n=='1'? 1:0);
  }
  char dummy;
  fscanf(infile, "%c", &dummy);
  return total;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start search or the keyword to search for. Thanks sixlettervariables

Comment: no problem. Every new person to C/C++ gets tripped up by what to call it.

Comment: @CarlNorum, Give him a break, Searching for the ternary operator is difficult since you need to know it is called the ternary operator first... I had the exact same problem many years ago, I ended up finding it by searching for "question mark operator".

Comment: That's my point - googling "question mark c" turns up [this link](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/The-question-mark-operator.html) as the first hit.

Comment: @CarlNorum, unless it ninja autocompletes your sentence into "question mark clipart".

Comment: Where do people get the idea that they can learn C without ever opening an introductory C book?

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
(n=='1'? 1:0)
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( n == '1' ) return 1
else return 0
```

So it returns 1 if n is '1' and 0 otherwise.

the format is:

```
( expression ? if-true-return-this-value : else-return-this-value )
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the ternary part is redundant in C: `n=='1'` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to an if statement.
Depending on whether the condition

`n=='1'`

is true or false, the operation will return the left side of (1:0) for true and the right side for false.

The values could be anything. 1 and 0 are random here.

```
if (n == '1') {
   return 1;
}
else {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not the same.  Using a ternary operator is part of an expression and yields a value.  An `if` statement does not.

Comment: You're right, let me edit that.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator here does this: "if n is equal to 1, then use 1, else use 0". So it will add 1 or 0 to the first expression based on n's value.

It's another way to write an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

this expression "(n=='1'? 1:0)" is equivalent to `if ( n == '1') return 1; else return 0;`
As stated, it is the ternary (conditional) operator in C.

And I'm guessing your code is loading then converting a binary string "0001010" to an integer.