# UITableViewRowAnimation - row is being deleted but with no animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement `UITableViewRowAnimation` like this:

```
[self.AroundersTableView beginUpdates];
[self.Arounders removeObjectAtIndex:cellRowToDelete];
[self.AroundersTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathesToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.AroundersTableView endUpdates];
```

The row is being deleted, but there is no animation.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure the view is rendered at least once as the error message suggests?

Comment: @neuhaus How to I do that?

Comment: @neuhaus I've checked it and the error isn't related to this animation, updated the post

Comment: "it's not working" is not good enough :-)

Comment: @neuhaus Haha, but I really don't have a clue why it's not working :), what do you need to know?

Comment: What are you seeing? Is the row being deleted? Is it being deleted but there is no animation?

Comment: @neuhaus Yes, the row is being deleted but there is no animation

Comment: The code isn't that bad. I'd assume the code isn't executed on the main thread. You can test it by wrapping your code with dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{ <your code> });

Comment: @Apoc Thank you! That's worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];`

Also, check out [UITableViewRowAnimationFade Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334221/uitableviewrowanimationfade-not-working)

Comment: Still the same problem... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[self.AroundersTableView beginUpdates]; 

[self.AroundersTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathesToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.Arounders removeObjectAtIndex:cellRowToDelete];

[self.AroundersTableView endUpdates];
```