# Objective-C operator (?) and (:)

Tags: objective-c, operators

What do the `?` and `:` signify here?

```
#define MAX(a,b) ( ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b) )
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `( ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b) )`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Kjuly mentioned it should be greater than sign, It's just an if statement.

```
(a > b) ? a : b
```

If `a` is greater than `b` then `a` will be returned from `MAX(a,b)` function or if `b` is greater then if statement will be false and `b` will be returned.

[The ternary (conditional) operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c)

Check Evan's answer

Answer (score 13):

This is a [*ternary operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) (also available in C, to which Objective C is a superset, and other languages that borrowed from it).

The expression before `?` is evaluated first; if it evaluates to non-zero, the subexpression before `:` is taken as the overall result; otherwise, the subexpression after the colon `:` is taken.

Note that subexpressions on both sides of `:` need to have the same type.

Also note that using macro for calculating `MAX` may produce unexpected results if arguments have side effects. For example, `MAX(++a, --b)` will produce a doubled side effect on one of the operands.

Answer (score 8):

`?:` is a ternary operator. What `((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b)` stands for is:

```
if (a > b)
  return a
else
  return b
```

Refter it [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 4):

This is a sort-of shorthand notation for a conditional.  a ? b : c.

If a evaluates to true, then b, else c.

I believe this should be: #define MAX(a,b) ( ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b) )

so basically, if a is greater then b, then a, else b