# Usage of ternary if

Tags: c, if-statement, ternary-operator

From Wikipedia, the following sections of code are equivalent:

```
if (a > b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

And:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

Obviously the use of the ternary if is much more concise, though not as clear.

What I'm wondering is: Is it bad (In terms of readability of code, execution time etc.) to use the ternary if instead of a traditional if statement?

Comment: It all depends on context. If it's a tiny, trivial comparison then no. Normally, probably, yes.

Comment: In that example, the use of the ternary is both more concise and *more* clear.

Comment: In contrast, see nested ternaries, ternaries used as rvalues, and side-effect-ful ternary operands.

Comment: because purrrrformmanncceeeee

Comment: To me this ternary is as much clear as `if...else`. It is very personal perception. There was kind of similar question somewhere, "Should I write code easier to understand for less skilled people." To me, if it looks good it's good. If you use 100+ character long ternary just to avoid `if..else`, then it starts to look stupid.

Comment: A few considerations that come to mind: 1. It is easier to debug (step into) the conventional `if/else` statements. 2. It will not be very readable once the operands are more than just "simple" variables. 3. In some cases, you'd be taking the risk of "unknown" operator-precedence, although I think that in most cases, the ternary operator has the lowest priority (not sure about bit-wise operators).

Comment: Duplicate question, too (cf link bottom of my answer [or click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c))

Comment: An embedded programmer must always say no to ternary operator no matter how smooth the bit*h feels !Hmmm CONST hmpf

Comment: @Geekasaur: actually, `const` are an argument in favour of the ternary operator, as I've explained at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Performance? how (except for `const` assignments)? Asserting ternaries affect performance is, AFAIK, unfounded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends. I can only think of *one* situation where a ternary operator undeniably *improves* readability and even performance (see bottom of this answer). But generally, using the ternary isn't going to improve readability/maintainability of your code. If you use it occasionally, and only for simple assignments then it's OK. not *good*, just acceptable IMO. Others are, of course, free to disgree with me on that.

Ternaries are expressions, so they should only be used as such (part of an assignment, for example). If you start using ternaries as statements, then you're in trouble. Ternaries are not *statements*, using them as such is like using a spoon as a screwdriver. Silly.

On the whole, though: it's a matter of taste as long as you don't overdo it. Once you start nesting ternaries, using them with pointers to pointers, or as statements, it's a matter of lunacy.
But to be honest: when in doubt: don't use the ternary operator. It saves you 1 line of code and doesn't improve performance. Take your example:

```
if (a > b) result = x;
else result = y;
//vs:
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

if `result` is the return value of a function, you could even write:

```
if (a > b) return x;
return y;
```

Even though I now have 2 return statements, I still find this code easier to read than:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
//or
return a > b ? x : y;
```

That one use-case where a ternary is the best option is this:

```
const int two_options = some_arg ? 23 : 1;
```

This enables you to define + initialize a `const` within a function's scope, depending on a condition, without the overhead of an additional function call (`const int two_opts = arg_func(some_arg);`, where the function contains the `if-else`)

Comment: +1, but with reluctance. E.g. in the case of simple assignments, it is rather "good" than "OK". "OK" sounds as if you'd want to say "If you absolutely want, then do it." That's too weak, IMHO. But I agree it is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @glglgl: I'm not saying good, because, as someone commented: debugging ternaries is _"harder"_ than debugging traditional `if-else`'s, especially when pointers are involved (`*some_ptr2ptr->foo = *arg ? *arg->foo : 0;` -> find the NULL pointer)

Comment: In this case, you don't have a "simple" assignment any longer, and readability is heavily affected, so I agree not to use it in this case.

Comment: @glglgl: Nips... fair point. Forgot to apply the rule I just advocated :-D

Comment: +1 For the const case.