# How does this return work?

Tags: c, function, operators

I found this piece of code and I am trying to figure out how it works, but I don't understand the part after the return statement. Can somebody explain this?

```
int f(int y)
{
  return (y<=1)?1:y*f(y-1);
}
```

Comment: read about conditional or ternary operators.

Comment: It is a recursive function.

Comment: fibonacci or something?

Comment: Factorial is my guess.

Comment: "If y is less than or equal to 1 then return 1 else return y times f(y-1)"

Comment: Ye its pretty insefficient version of factorial

Comment: When you say you want help figuring it out, can you please be more specific? There are three things going on: The ternary expression (the `?:` bit), the recursion (the call again to `f`), and the algorithm itself. Which is it you have trouble figuring out?

Comment: Might also get trouble with *integer overflow*.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a very bad way to write programs. Not only is the algorithm hard to read, it also makes the program needlessly inefficient. As a rule of thumb, only use recursion as a very last resort. It has very limited practical use. Unfortunately books and teachers spend far too much time teaching about such a useless, inefficient, dangerous feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
int f(int y)
{
  return (y<=1) ? 1 : y*f(y-1);
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int f(int y)
{
  if(y <= 1)
  {
    return 1;
  } else
  {
    return y*f(y-1);
  }
}
```

which should be clear to you by now, that it's a recursive function that uses [The ternary (conditional) operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c).

The ternary operator has this general form:

> condition ? a : b

where if `condition` evaluates into *True*, then `a` will be executed, else `b`.

Comment: Remove the braces around `(condition)`. They are not part of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you @PaulOgilvie, it didn't feel right to be honest! :)

Comment: Also (see that only now): remove the `;`. (`;` is a statement terminator and turns an expression into a statement, but this is only an expression, so _no_ `;`)