# Understanding a tricky for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a question regarding the for loop in the release list func. (The head is a dummy so we don't need to release it). I don't understand the:

```
next = next?
```

part in the loop. What does it actually do, and why simply

```
next?
```

won't suffice? here is the code:

```
typedef struct NODE {
int num;
struct NODE* next;
} Node;




void release_list(Node* head) {
    Node* next = head->next ? head->next->next : NULL;
    for( Node* curr = head->next;
         curr != NULL;
         curr = next, next = next? next->next : NULL) {
        free(curr);
     }
}
```

Comment: It's the [conditional (a.k.a. ternary) operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). I know there's a good duplicate question, but I just can't seem to find it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than assignment `=`.

Code is equivalent to:

```
next = (next? next->next : NULL)
```

Or:

```
if(next != NULL)
    next = next->next;
else
    next = NULL;
```

Point of the code is to avoid accidentally doing `NULL->next` on last element.

Answer (score 3):

The part :

```
curr = next, next = next? next->next : NULL
```

is the third part of the `for` loop, which means that it will be executed each time it ends. It is equivalent to  :

```
curr = next;
if (next)                 //if next != NULL
    next = next->next;
else
    next = NULL;
```

What the code is trying to achieve is to check all pointers so as to avoid trying to access `NULL->next` on the last element, which will not exist.

---

In general, an `if` statement like the following :

```
if (a > b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

can be rewritten as the following statement:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

as shown in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C).

You can read more about the [Ternary operator in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/ternary_operator_examples.htm).

Comment: Shouldn't it then be `next == next?` Otherwise it is an assignment, not a comparison, isn't it?

Comment: @arc_lupus I didn't get it, what are you saying that should be `next == next`?

Comment: The answer from @user694733 solved it for me, was a misunderstanding, sorry!

Comment: Good answer, but I know the operator. The mistake was misreading: I thought it was: (next =next?) next->next : NULL) which didn't make sense. Thanks

Comment: @Bar glad if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop can be rewritten as a while loop, as follows:

```
Node* curr = head->next;
while(curr != NULL)
{
    free(curr);
    curr = next;
    if (next != NULL)
    {
        next = next->next;
    }
    else
    {
        next = NULL;
    }
}
```

The intention of `next = next?next->next:NULL` is to move the `next` pointer to its next node.

See: [The ternary (conditional) operator in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of the `?:` operator. The construct is `cond?consequent:alternative`. If `cond` evaluates `true` the expression `consequent` is evaluated and it's value is the result of the expression, otherwise `alternative` is evaluated and it's value is the result of the expression. The type of `consequent` and `alternative` should be the same.

So `next ? next->next : NULL` means `next->next` if `next` is not `NULL` and `NULL` if `next` is `NULL`.

Additionally the `,` operator means to evaluate the expressions in sequence. This is the lowest prioritized operator which means that the last of the `for` clause means that first evaluate `curr = next` and then `next = next ? next->next : NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of *obscuation* and almost certainly the code is a failed attempt to delete all nodes in a linked list. A faster and more readable way to do the same would be:

```
void release_list (Node* head)
{
  while(head != NULL)
  {
    Node* tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp); 
  }
}
```