# explain these how the conditional operator helps in counting the negative and positive numbers in an array?

Tags: c

my confusion is that how in the program the number of positive and negative numbers are calculated by writing that piece of code shown.
explain these code please!

```
int num[5], i, neg = 0, pos = 0;

printf("enter any 5 numbers");
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    num[i] < 0 ? neg++ : (pos++);
}
printf("\nnegative elements=%d", neg);
printf("\npositive elements=%d", pos);
getch();
```

Comment: As for your problem, you *do* know how the [ternary (conditional) expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758849/the-ternary-conditional-operator-in-c) works?

Comment: Compiler does not calculate anything, FYI.

Comment: maybe i don't exactly know!

Comment: The ternary operator works as follows: `condition ? execute if true : execute if false`.

Comment: `num[i]<0?neg++:(pos++);` ---> `if (num[i]<0) neg++; else pos++;`

Comment: okay! but what neg++ do to give the printf statement the number of negative number.

Comment: Well, you should by a good c book and look at increment and if condition....

Comment: How about reading a book on C programming ?

Comment: maybe you are right, i have a book not able to find it there and thought will get a quick answer here

Comment: It actually doesn't do anything meaningful to help. It's just used as syntactic sugar to replace a proper if statement. This code fails code review in my book. It's worse than the if, since operator precedence can make it fail gloriously. That's why `pos++` is in parentheses.

Comment: lol i am getting it now every time neg++ is true neg is incremented by 1!

Answer (score 1):

```
 num[i]<0?neg++:(pos++);
```

Here, If number **less then zero** then condition become `true` and count the **negative** numbers and If number **not less then zero** then condition become `false` and count **positive** numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
num[i]<0?neg++:(pos++);
```

means- compare num[i] to 0, if it is lower, increase the variable neg. Otherwise (num[i] >= 0), increase the variable pos.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since, most answers have explained the ternary operator, I need not do it again.
The neg++ **post-increments** the previous value of **neg** variable. And the same goes for pos++.
Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators) on post/pre increments.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator used as an expression statement evaluates like an `if` statement:

```
num[i] < 0 ? neg++ : (pos++);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (num[i] < 0)
    neg++;
else
    pos++;
```

This kind of coding is not considered good style, and there are other issues in the code fragment posted:

- the return value of `scanf()` should be checked to avoid undefined behavior if the input cannot be converted to an `int`.
- the loop index should be compared to the array size with `i < 5` instead of using the `<=` operator and a close but different constant.
- output lines should be terminated with newline, not initiated with one.
- `getch()` is a non standard function.  Its purpose is to force a pause before the program exits. Fixing shortcomings of the environment inside the program is a sad workaround. Opening a terminal window to execute programs is a better alternative: it allows the programmer to observe all program output including any extra runtime messages occurring upon program termination.

Comment: Thanks for these valuable tips, i'm little confused about how to check the scanf() return value and last one how to open a terminal window to execute program.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. In your case it should return `1` if an integer number was stored into `num[i]`. To open a terminal window, in Windows use the start menu, run, `cmd.exe`.